# libgdx, java - trying to call a .render() from another class

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hello I am trying to draw "whiteballoon" in main from a serperate class called whiteBalloon.  The point is , whenever I call this class's method render() I want to be able to have multiple sprites on screen, clones of each other.  The below code is giving me a null exception..

this is the class that i am calling from the main loop.

```
class whiteBalloon{
    Sprite whiteballoon;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    public whiteBalloon(SpriteBatch batch){


    }
    public void create(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        whiteballoon = new Sprite(new Texture("white_balloon.png"));
        whiteballoon.setPosition(0, 0);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }

    public void render(){

        System.out.println("hey");

        batch.begin();
        whiteballoon.draw(batch);
        batch.end();



    }

}
```

and then i call it by using

```
whiteBalloon grumpface;
        grumpface = new whiteBalloon();
        grumpface.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `grumpface.create()` before `grumpface.render()` or just put `create()` method inside constructor:

```
public whiteBalloon(){
    create();
}
```

Also your constructor requires a `SpriteBatch` object as argument, but you don't provide it later in code, so it uses default (empty) constructor instead of the one you created.